# Weird behaviour of string split function across different languages

Tags: java, ruby, string, split

Why does

```
"a\t\t\t\t\t".split("\t").length
```

return 1 and

```
"a\t\t\t\t\ta".split("\t").length
```

return 6?

This applies both to Java and Ruby, but I would actually expect that it would return 5 in the first case. Is this a design choice in Java?

Javascript behaves differently and does actually return 5.

Comment: Because `split` is not some universally defined operation that works the same across languages. You should read the documentation and see what it does on a case by case basis.

Comment: I was asking if there is an explicit reason as to why Ruby and Java implement this kind of counter-intuitive (at least for me) behaviour.

Comment: Read the docs. With `limit` left out, `split` autodetects how many "actual" columns there are. Use the `limit` to adjust what you want `split` to do if you don't want it to autodetect.

Comment: [The ruby documentation](https://www.rubydoc.info/stdlib/core/String#split-instance_method) states: *"If the limit parameter is omitted, trailing null fields are suppressed"*. Different languages handle edge cases in different ways. It's very subjective what the "intuitive" behaviour should be here. If ruby were to copy JavaScipt's implementation, then we would be seeing StackOverflow questions like "why doesn't ruby behave like Java?".

Comment: I can think of many scenarios where this "counter-intuitive" (in your opinion) behaviour would actually be preferable. But if you need to explicitly get the same behaviour as e.g. JavaScript here, use `str.split(limit: -1)`.

Comment: @TomLord when parsing a TSV file that has a line with trailing empty fields (i.e. ending with several tabs) you have to handle this case separately (or use the -1 limit as you just pointed out, which I didn't know)

Comment: @TheCodingMonk When parsing a TSV file, you should be using [ruby's built-in `CSV` library](https://ruby-doc.org/stdlib/libdoc/csv/rdoc/CSV.html) (with `col_sep: "\t"`), not `String#split`. Sounds like your question was really more of an [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/66377/369864) to me, since you're using the wrong tool for the job.

Comment: Ruby is an object-oriented language, not an arrays-of-strings oriented language. (Unless your object really is best described by an array of strings, of course!). If you're dealing with a `csv` file, use the `CSV` parser.

Comment: If I produce a simple TSV file that can be easily parsed by splitting \t instead of introducing an extra dependency (e.g. for Java where there's no built-in CSV/TSV parser) I always go for the first and simplest way, which is using String#split. Nonetheless, I realize the behaviour of the split function is a totally subjective matter, still it is counter-intuitive to me because, as a matter of fact, there actually 5 empty strings in between that are not returned.